# What is a best practice to store 'large' data, represented by List in Java, in database?

Tags: java, jpa, jta

What is a best practice to store 'large' data, represented by List in Java, in database?

i'm considering  3 variants:

1. Use '@OneToMany' to store data in separate table.
2. Serialize data and store it in parent table.
3. Store data as files(naming conventions? same as id?).

> To be more specific

'Large' data entities:

```
class SingleSleeper{

    private Double startPositionOnLeft;
    private Double endPositionOnLeft;
    private Double startPositionOnRight;
    private Double endPositionOnRight;
....
}

class RutEntry{

    private Double width;
    private Double position;
...
}
```

There are about 50 instances of `SingleSleeper` class and about 25000 instances of `RutEntry` class in one parent instance. Parent instances are generated about 40 times every day.
i'm using EclipseLink JPA 2.1, derby

> Addition

Most of all i'm interested in best readability in Java. But i'm afraid that database speed will significantly decrease if i will store too much data into database. An overwhelming number of requests will be to select all instances of SingleSleeper or RutEntry classes of particular parent entity. I'm not interested for support to different database types, but i can move to other database, if needed.

Comment: That's a very vague question: Are you interested in best performance when storing, best performance when selecting (for a specific query?), best storage size, best readability in Java, best support for different database types (which others do you have in mind?). Only thing I can tell: Use a `ManyToOne` on the child entity instead of a `OneToMany` on the parent entity, if you have many child entities.

Comment: @Tobias Most of all i'm interested in best readability in Java. But i'm afraid that database speed will significantly decrease if i will store too much data into database. An overwhelming number of requests will be to select all instances of SingleSleeper or RutEntry classes of particular parent entity. I'm not interested for support to different database types, but i can move to other database, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do neither of your variants.

I would add a `ManyToOne` to the child entities (which is somehow the opposite of your first variant):

```
public class SingleSleeper {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private ParentEntity parent;

   ...
}

public class RutEntry {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private ParentEntity parent;

}
```

This ensures that you have a mapping and that you *never* load all 25000 entities for a parent object, if you don't need them (the lazy fetch ensures that you even don't need to load the parent entity).

You *can* create a `OneToMany` in the parent object with a `mappedBy` link, if you really want to. For example because you always need all child objects in the parent entity:

```
class ParentEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Collection<SingleSleeper> singleSleepers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Collection<RutEntry> rutEntries;
}
```

But I don't know how EclipseLink is working here - for Hibernate you need at least an additional `BatchSize` annotation to indicate that it should load as many child entities as possible at once. It can't fetch all together with the parent instance (e.g. by defining both as `FetchType.EAGER`), as only one is allowed to be fetched eagerly (and otherwise you would have 25000 * 50 result rows in the result set of the corresponding SQL select statement).

The best to load all child entities for a parent entity is to load them separate, either using *JPQL* (easier to read, faster to write) or the *Criteria API* (typesafe, but you need a *metamodel*):

```
ParentEntity parent = entityManager.find(ParentEntity.class, id);

// JPQL:
List<SingleSleeper> singleSleepers = entityManager.createQuery(
   "SELECT s FROM SingleSleeper s WHERE s.parent = %parent"
   ).setParameter("parent", parent).getResultList();

// Or Criteria API:
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SingleSleeper> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(SingleSleeper.class);
Root<SingleSleeper> s = query.from(SingleSleeper.class);
query.select(s).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(s.get(SingleSleeper_.parent), parent));
List<SingleSleeper> singleSleepers = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

You have three advantages of that approach:

1. Still easy to read - if you put the loading into its own method.
2. You are flexible to decide when to load the 25050 children.
3. You can load a subset of the children as well (by modifying the result of `createQuery` with `Query.setFirstResult` and `Query.setMaxResults`).

Comment: Thanks, but what about speed? For example, if there are 100 000 parent entities in database? Will other variants faster and why?

Comment: I have no experience with Derby - so I don't know how that performs with tables with more than 100 000 * 25 000 entries. But that sounds already like a _big data_ problem, as the working load for Rutentry with two doubles (without any management and indexing overhead) would take approx. 55 GByte. So you should check for other solutions beside SQL databases as well. Concerning my approach compared with your 3 variants: none of yours will be faster.

Comment: What is that other solutions?

Comment: What _are_ those other solutions: Read the [Wikipedia entry about Big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data).

Comment: Just performed small test of persisting 10 entities. `@ElementCollection` approach vs `Serialization` on the same machine. Result: 30s vs 500ms, accordingly. Is it ok? Maybe i'm just didn't configure database/server correctly?

Comment: I can't find the `@ElementCollection` approach in your query? And there must be something wrong, if an entity takes 3 seconds to persists (although JPA is not the fastest way to store data - compared to extracting data from the database).